# How to utilize disk space of Amazon EBS attached to a DCOS Agent machine

Tags: dcos

We have EBS attached to our centos machines which are used as DCOS agent machines. However when a DCOS cluster is
created, the mounted EBS storage is not utilized for Total DCOS disk capacity.

Please can you let me know, if there are anyways to include them. The DCOS otherwise is working properly and we are able to execute applications ( ArangoDB, Spark ) in them.

I've checked this link : https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/storage/external-storage/ . But it doesn't seem to solve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mount Disk Resources](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/storage/mount-disk-resources/) is probably what you are looking for.

You can learn more about Mount/Path disk at the [Mesos documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/multiple-disk/).